# Np.where change value in column if another column value is in another dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Let me explain the structure of the problem that I'm trying to solve.
Let's suppose that we have two dataframes

DF1:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| AA | 2 |
| AB | 1 |
| AC | 2 |
| AD | 1 |
| AE | 2 |

DF2:

| ID | New Value |
| --- | --- |
| AA | 1 |
| AC | 1 |

If the ID column row in DF1 is in DF2, then I would like to change the value in the same row in DF1 to the one that it has in DF2, so the end result would be something like this:

DF1:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| AA | 1 |
| AB | 1 |
| AC | 1 |
| AD | 1 |
| AE | 2 |

So far, I have tried attempts with .loc and np.where but none of them where successful, my closest attempt is the following line of code:

```
DF1['Value'][row] = [DF2['New Value'][row] if ((DF1['ID'][row]).isin(DF2['ID'])) else DF1['Value'][row] for row in DF['ID']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to to do it using map

```
# set index on ID in DF2 and map to DF
# replace failed mapping with the value in DF
df['Value']=df['ID'].map(df2.set_index(['ID'])['New Value']).fillna(df['Value'])
df
```

```
    ID  Value
0   AA  1.0
1   AB  1.0
2   AC  1.0
3   AD  1.0
4   AE  2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go straight with `merge` then `ffill`

Data:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a','b','c'],
                   'val':[1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a','c'],
                   'newval':[10,20]})
```

Merge df1 and df2

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='name', how='left')
```

Now you ffill (forward fill). This means you take two columns `val` and `newval`. Any missing value in `newval` is filled by value in `val`. The `axis=1` means you fill by rows not by column

```
df[['val', 'newval']] = df[['val', 'newval']].ffill(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
# df1

   ID  Value
0  AA      2
1  AB      1
2  AC      2
3  AD      1
4  AE      2

# df2

   ID  New Value
0  AA          1
1  AC          1
```

Doing:

```
# Set Indices
df1, df2 = [df.set_index('ID') for df in (df1, df2)]

# Use loc:
df1.loc[df2.index, 'Value'] = df2['New Value']

print(df1.reset_index())
```

Output:

```
   ID  Value
0  AA      1
1  AB      1
2  AC      1
3  AD      1
4  AE      2
```